# Learning PHP - Understanding how WP_MEMORY_LIMIT works in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning PHP and I have been looking at this code: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/493f76a3d2ef8c030ab5dcd4333f9a401208f534/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L34-L43

```
// Define memory limits.
if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M' );
    }
}
```

Lines 34-43 in the default-constants.php file that is included in the WordPress CMS.

Am I right that if I were to translate the code to words that this is basically what it means:

If WP_MEMORY_LIMIT is not already defined:

- If the PHP memory_limit is not changeable, that is to say wp_is_ini_value_changeable('memory_limit') returns false then WP will use the current_limit as the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT

The variable is defined on line 31:
$current_limit     = @ini_get( 'memory_limit' );

- If the PHP memory limit is changeable, then wp_is_ini_value_changeable('memory_limit') returns true, which means that if it is a multisite it will be defined as 64M or if it is regular installation it will be 40M

Would you say this is a correct translation of the code?

Does this mean that WP will only default to 40M/64M if the PHP memory limit can be changed?

And let's say that $current_limit returns 2000M and you define WP_MEMORY_LIMIT as 512M in the wp-config.php file, will WP then only allocate max 512M of memory even if the server allows more?

Any input is appreciated, and thank you!

Comment: Please quote the code here as text, don't just link elsewhere.

Comment: My apologies @deceze - I have added the code to my description

Comment: After that WP calls `ini_set( 'memory_limit', a-number );` - are you effectively asking when that will/will-not work (the code quoted in the question doesn't actually 'do' anything - except define a constant)? Generally, I do not think it's a good idea to learn PHP by reading Wordpress' source code. If appropriate please edit the question to avoid [an x/y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - i.e. to answer what you ultimately want to know, not the thing you found whilst trying to figure that out :).